# swift - AppDelegate.applicationDidBecomeActive does not fire

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

The AppDelegate.applicationDidBecomeActive does note fire after reopening application.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    print("app did become active")
```

Comment: restart your xcode and try

Comment: Did you remove any code or change in project setting? did you try by creating new scratch project?

Comment: It's called when app first time launch and app comes from background to foreground

Comment: Try sceneDidBecomeActive